# Unable to navigate to specific viewController after clicking push notification in foreground using FCM below iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to get the notification in foreground as well as in background, i am getting notification in both states, but i'm unable to navigate it to desired view controller after tapping the notification when app is in foreground, Any help will be highly appreciated, thanks in advance
    i am using third party for custom banner, running on iphone 4s device, ios 9

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
 // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification
    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics

    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    print("In did Recieve Notification")
    // Print message ID.
    print("userInfoNotification=\(userInfo)")
    if let contactID = userInfo["contactID"] as? String {
        self.contactID = contactID
        print(contactID)
    }
    let state = UIApplication.shared.applicationState
    if state == .active {
        print("App in Foreground")

        if self.contactID != AppDelegate.openedChatContactId {
            print("openedID=\(AppDelegate.openedChatContactId)")
            if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
                if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary {
                    let body = alert["body"] as! String
                    let title = alert["title"] as! String
                    let banner = Banner(title: title, subtitle: body, image: UIImage(named: "AppIcon"), backgroundColor: UIColor(red:31.00/255.0, green:136.0/255.0, blue:254.5/255.0, alpha:1.000))
                    banner.dismissesOnTap = true
                    banner.show(duration: 3.0)

                      //  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                     //   let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "chatMessageVC") as! ChatMessagesVC
                     // UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController;
                } else if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSString {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if state == .inactive || state == .background {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var destinationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "chatMessageVC") as! ChatMessagesVC
        UserDefaults.standard.set(contactID, forKey: "contactID")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        destinationViewController.contactID = self.contactID
        let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
        navigationController.pushViewController(destinationViewController, animated: false)

    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting storyboard and viewController? is it navigationController or tabbarController type app?

Comment: @PPL it is a navigationController type app

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: this method get called?

Comment: @kunalkushwaha Hope you can upvote too, It may help others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement below extension of `UIApplication`

```
extension UIApplication {
    class func topViewController(controller: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(controller: navigationController.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tabController.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(controller: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = controller?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(controller: presented)
        }
        return controller
    }
}
```

Please change your code to navigate to specific screen while app is in foreground.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "chatMessageVC") as! ChatMessagesVC
UIApplication.topViewController()?.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: false)
```

Hope this finds you well and let me know in case of any queries.

**UPDATE**

If the application is running in the *foreground*, iOS won't show a notification banner/alert. That's by design. But we can achieve it by using *UILocalNotification* as follows

```
if application.applicationState == .active {
    var localNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.userInfo = userInfo
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    localNotification.alertBody = message
    localNotification.fireDate = Date()
    UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
}
```

Comment: it want  to navigate to ChatMessageVC when push notification is tapped in foreground.

Comment: it automatically navigates to ChatMessageVC, when notification is received.

Comment: it will because user is in foreground state

Comment: if app is in foreground it won't show alert or banner, if you want to display it then see my updated code

Comment: i have used third party, I am able to show the push notification in foreground, but unable to navigate it while tapping on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170613/discussion-between-ppl-and-kunal-kushwaha).